# phpmailer class and accented characters

Tags: php, forms, class, character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer class to sending emails. Now, i come from Europe, so we used accented characters... but they're bad handled from my php script, and i don't know why.. i tried to change many times from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 And vice versa from my html form, script.php,  and class.phpmailer.php unsuccessfully. (class.phpmailer.php by default is iso-8859-1)

```
//My form.html
...
  <form action="script.php" name="contatti" method="POST" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">

  </form>
...

//My script.php
...
  require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

  $messaggio = new PHPmailer();
  $messaggio->CharSet = "ISO-8859-1";
...


//class.phpmailer.php
...
    public $CharSet           = 'utf-8';
...
```

Sorry for my english.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Encoding should be consistent all over the places. So lets stick to utf-8. First of all check if your website is UTF-8 encoded. You should look for something like this in your HTML:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Then replace your "ISO-8859-1" to utf-8 and look what you have now.

Comment: Many times i tried with:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

The issue still exists.